# A^n=I iff A is diagonalisable

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Prove that $A^n=I$ over an field $\mathbb{F}$ of char 0 iff $A$ is diagonalisable with $n$-th roots of unity  on the diagonal.

Remark: One direction is clear. For the other dierection: Assume $A^n=I$ then $x^n-1=0$ is an annihilating polynomial for $A$ and so all eigenvalues are $n$-th roots of unity; but how to prove $A$ diagonalisable? I aim to show its minimal polynomial has no repeated roots by using Jordan normal form..

Comment: The minimal polynomial divides $x^n - 1$. If $x^n - 1$ has distinct roots, then so must the minimal polynomial.

Comment: Please edit the title so that it becomes a correct statement: as it is now, it isn 't!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The claim is false without further conditions on the field. For example

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}\in\mathcal M_2(\overline{\Bbb F}_2)$$

has $\,x^2-1=(x-1)^2\,$ as characteristic and minimal polynomial and thus $\,A^2=I\,$ ,  yet it even isn't diagonalizable...

**Added as a result of an added condition:** if $\,\operatorname {char}\Bbb F=0\,$ then
all the roots of $\,x^n-1\,$ are simple (why?), and since the definition field $\,\Bbb F\,$ is algebraically closed then we can write

$$x^n-1=\prod_{i}(x-a_i)$$

where $\,a_i^n=1\,$ are $\,n\,$-th roots of unit in the field. Since clearly the characteristic and the minimal polynomial of $\,A\,$ coincide in this case (why?), the last one can be written as a product of *different* linear factors and thus $\,A\,$ is diagonalizable, with its eigenvalues, i.e. the roots of unit $\,a_i'\,$s, on its main diagonal.

Comment: Yeah, it assumes char(F)=0.

Comment: Sir, in given question $f(x)= x^n-1 $ is annihilating polynomial of $A$. How we conclude that it is characteristic polynomial? and yes by definition of minimal polynomial we have minimal polynomial divides $f(x)$ but it is not necessary that all roots of $f(x)$ are roots of minimal/ characteristic polynomial of $A$. Please help.

Comment: @AkashPatalwanshi You can't conclude $\;f\;$ it's the characteristic polynomial, unless it is given, for example, that the order of $\;A\;$ is $\;n\times n\;$

Comment: The roots of the minimal polynomial, and thus of the charac. polynomial as well, as armong the roots of $\;x^n-1\;$ , thus: they are roots of unity of order $\;n\;$ .

Comment: Sir thank you so... much for your reply and for your last comment.